# Will Firefox not "correctly" open links with a target="_blank" attribute added on page load by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm using the following code (with the Underscore.js library) to add the attributes `target="_blank"` and `rel="external"` to all non-local links on page load. My code looks like the following:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){

        // Create a matching regex pattern based on current host name
        var regexPattern = new RegExp(location.origin);

        // Gather all non-local links
        nonLocalLinks = _(jQuery('a')).reject(function(link) { 

            return link.href.match(regexPattern);

        });

        // Add attributes to all non-local links
        _(nonLocalLinks).each(function(item) { 
            item.target = '_blank'; 
            item.rel = 'external';
        });

    })
})(jQuery)
```

This code works correctly in all tested browsers (Chrome 17, IE7, IE8, IE9, Safari) but does not work in Firefox 10. Links that had the `target="_blank"` attribute set on the anchor tag as part of the HTML output by the server function as expected. Will this not work on page load in Firefox, or is there something else I'm missing?

Also - I appreciate any and all input, but please don't suggest that this is bad user experience, etc. I agree, but I don't have a choice - this is for a client, and this is what they want; "no" is not an option.

EDIT: This "does not work" means that the link opens in the same tab. There are no errors in the firebug console - the link simply behaves as though `target="_blank"` is not set.

Comment: Why are you setting "target" directly but "rel" with the jQuery "attr" function>? If you *must* use jQuery there for some reason, you should be using ".prop()" and not ".attr()", almost certainly. And when you say it does not work, exactly what is the problem? How can you tell it doesn't work.

Comment: That was a vestige of old code - thanks for pointing it out. Fixed in the question and the actual source. Added additional detail to the question.

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you would post that regex, because it's possible that that's where the problem lies.

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/QYbZR/) is a simple jsfiddle demonstrating that adding "target" to `<a>` links via JavaScript works perfectly well in Firefox.

Comment: @Pointy - your comment about the regex lead me to the issue. The location object does not have an `origin` property in Firefox. I updated it to `location.origin || location.host`, and now it works. Any chance you could put that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Go ahead and accept mu is too short's answer :-)  Glad I could help!

Comment: Why not filtering external links by comparing the hosts without a regular expression? `return link.host===location.host` in your `reject` call.

Comment: @Pointy: Or you can put it down and take the checkmark, I'm happy to see the problem solved regardless of who gets the glory.

Comment: How did this work for you in IE, exactly?  IE doesn't have an `origin` property on location objects...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox doesn't have an `origin` property on `window.location`. That means that your `regexPattern` ends up being `//` and that leaves `nonLocalLinks` empty.

Demo (watch the console): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/tS4WB/

You'll have to account for a missing `location.origin` with something like this:

```
var origin = location.origin;
if(!origin)
    origin = location.protocol + '//' + location.host;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/envWe/

You might want to add an `^` anchor to your regex as well or just check if [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) gives you zero.

If you have a look at the [MDN documentation on `window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location), you'll see that the following properties are supported:

- hash
- host
- hostname
- href
- pathname
- port
- protocol
- search

No origin.